# MariaDB 10.1.16 on Ubuntu fails to start: WSREP Failed to recover position

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu, galera, mariadb-10.1

I'm using `10.1.16-MariaDB-1~xenial` from the [official MariaDB apt repository for 10.1 [stable], via the University of Texas mirror](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=ut-austin&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.1).

I had a perfectly functioning MariaDB Galera cluster setup on 3 Ubuntu 16.04 servers.

Then I upgraded them. Now I have nothing.

The upgrade to 10.1.16 failed, and quickly brought down the whole cluster. I don't have the output, but dpkg failed on setting up `mariadb-server` and `mariadb-server-10.1`.

I have backups, so I purged all traces of MariaDB/MySQL/Galera from my servers (including removing `/var/lib/mysql/`, `/etc/mysql/`, and `/var/log/mysql/`) and started over. However, now, with a clean install on each server, none of the standard system startup scripts work. I suspect this is why the upgrade process through `apt` failed, too.

I've tried each of the following on my first node:

```
galera_new_cluster
service mysql bootstrap
service mysql bootstrap --wsrep-new-cluster
service mysql bootstrap --wsrep-cluster-address="gcomm://"
service mysql start
service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
service mysql start --wsrep-cluster-address="gcomm://"
systemctl start mariadb
systemctl start mariadb --wsrep-new-cluster
systemctl start mariadb --wsrep-cluster-address="gcomm://"
```

Every single one gives me the same output:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status mariadb.service`:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-07-22 13:29:45 CDT; 42s ago
  Process: 10799 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ] &&   systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10794 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16865 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 22 13:29:41 sql2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jul 22 13:29:45 sql2 mysqld[10799]: WSREP: Failed to recover position: '2016-07-22 13:29:41 140110745778432 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.16-MariaDB-1~xenial) starting as process 11080 ...'
Jul 22 13:29:45 sql2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 22 13:29:45 sql2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jul 22 13:29:45 sql2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 22 13:29:45 sql2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The **only** way I can start my servers now is by manually executing:

```
sudo -u mysql mysqld --wsrep-cluster-address='gcomm://'
```

On the first node, and then:

```
sudo -u mysql mysqld --wsrep-cluster-address='gcomm://ip1,ip2,ip3'
```

On the other two nodes. That works, and I have a working cluster again. But now, systemd/systemctl have no idea the service is running. It seems like the systemd startup scripts can't use the `wsrep-cluster-address` setting in my configuration files at all. Specifying it to `service` or `systemctl` command line does not work either.

How am I supposed to start mariadb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug in galera_recovery.sh script.
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10396

Comment: Patching `/usr/bin/galera_recovery` per the bug comments fixed my issue on each one of the cluster servers that I upgraded to 10.1.16, hopefully this will make it into a release coming soon. and this comment will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to temporarily alleviate my problems by downgrading to 10.1.14:

```
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/libmariadbclient18_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/libmysqlclient18_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-client-core-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-common_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_all.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mariadb-server-core-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.1/mysql-common_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_all.deb
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/files/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.14/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/g/galera-3/galera-3_25.3.15-xenial_amd64.deb
apt purge mariadb-server
apt autoremove --purge
apt clean
rm -rf /etc/mysql/
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
rm -rf /var/log/mysql/
rm -f /var/log/mysql.*
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service
rm -f /etc/rc0.d/K03mysql
rm -f /etc/rc1.d/K03mysql
rm -f /etc/rc2.d/S03mysql
rm -f /etc/rc3.d/S03mysql
rm -f /etc/rc4.d/S03mysql
rm -f /etc/rc5.d/S03mysql
rm -f /etc/rc6.d/K03mysql
rm -f /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysql.service
rm -f /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysqld.service
rm -f /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
rm -f /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
rm -rf /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service
rm -f /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mariadb.service.dsh-also
rm -f /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service
rm -f /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysql.service
rm -f /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysqld.service
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt update
apt install iproute libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl libjemalloc1 liblwp-mediatypes-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl socat
dpkg -i mysql-common_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_all.deb 
dpkg -i mariadb-common_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_all.deb 
dpkg -i libmariadbclient18_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb libmysqlclient18_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb mariadb-client-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb mariadb-client-core-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb mariadb-server-core-10.1_10.1.14+maria-1~xenial_amd64.deb galera-3_25.3.15-xenial_amd64.deb
```

Now, I can start my first node with `galera_new_cluster` and all other nodes with `service mysql start`.

There must be a bug with the systemd/systemctl scripts in 10.1.16.